# ContentPresenter with ContentTemplateSelector within DataContext = NULL context?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store application that ueses datatemplates and datatemplateselectors to style various content for display.

I have a TemplateSelector that returns a Template based an parameters. This template also uses a contentpresenter which itself has a TemplateSelector.

I have tried calling the inner TemplateSelector in this ways:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
<Grid>
    <Border Background="{StaticResource ApplicationBackgroundBrush}">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding DataContext}">
                <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector>
                    <my:MyTemplateSelector />
                </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Using the TemplateBinding, i get an exception that the DataContext Property cannot be found (DependencyProperty cannot be created from string).

My first attempt was this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
<Grid>
    <Border Background="{StaticResource ApplicationBackgroundBrush}">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DataContext}">
                <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector>
                    <my:MyTemplateSelector />
                </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The problem with this is that the Content and DataContext are null when the TemplateSelector gets called. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Ran into the same problem.  This is not looking promising.  I'm thinking of using the ItemsControl with a single item as a hack-workaround.  Did you ever solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I had a similar problem because I missed the Property Keyword. Hope it applies to your situation.

```
Content={TemplateBinding Property=DataContext}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use ContentControl instead of ContentPresenter.

Comment: As this was a question from 4 years ago, this might have changed since then. I can't verify as i currently am not working on any windows store app right now.

Comment: I've just posted the answer for future use.